# Get equally padded keys from middle of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JS code, which should return the first and last items in an array and then increments from the remaining items.

So for example:

```
var numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten'];
var values = [];
values.push(numbers[0]); // get first
values.push(numbers[numbers.length-1]); // get last
numbers = numbers.slice(1, numbers.length-1); // remove the first and last from numbers
console.log(numbers); // (numbers will go from 2-9 now)
var interval = 2;
for (var i = interval; i < numbers.length; i+=interval) { // get every 2nd item
  values.push(numbers[i]);
}
console.log(values);
```

Which returns:

```
["One", "Ten", "Four", "Six", "Eight"]
```

So re-ordered gives me:

```
["One", "Four", "Six", "Eight", "Ten"]
```

But if the data set changes to have Eleven the end result will be:

```
["One", "Eleven", "Four", "Six", "Eight", "Ten"]
```

Re-ordered gives:

```
["One", "Four", "Six", "Eight", "Ten", "Eleven"]
```

So the problem is here is that `Ten` and `Eleven` are right next to each other and not as equal spaced as the other items.

The only way I could think to avoid this was to check the length of the array and see if it's an even number or not and then increment the interval to be odd if this is the case. e.g.

```
if (interval % 2 != 0)
    interval = interval + 1;
```

However what I find is that sometimes you can still end up with an item next to the last item that isn't spaced the same as the others in the list if the math works out, because after doing the slice, the second to last item in the array is now the last so if the loop interval ends up being perfectly matched to this index, you end up with that item.

How can I avoid this? Basically always pick the first and last items and then equally pad the items out in the middle to a given interval I can pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just calculate the index for getting an equal spaced array.

```js
function getValues(array, count) {
    var last = array.pop(),
        values = [];

    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        values.push(array[Math.floor(i * array.length / (count - 1))]);
    }
    return values.concat(last);
}

console.log(getValues(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten'], 5));
console.log(getValues(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven'], 5));
```

For a really same distance distribution, you could have a look to the [euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), or better use [bjorklunds algorithm](https://ics-web.sns.ornl.gov/timing/Rep-Rate%20Tech%20Note.pdf), which insert spaces equally around the items. The more popular title is [euclideans rhythm](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/banff.pdf).

Comment: That's pretty slick! Could explain what you're doing in your loop to get the equal spacing? Thanks.

Comment: it's just choping up the array in equal parts. the fooring move the index with a priority to bottom. therfore you could add the last item to the result set without any need to sort afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify what your goal is. It seems like you want evenly spaced values including the first and last items but you haven't formally specified this and you haven't said whether intervals of 2 are preferred for some reason.